# Getting the current element that invoked a function?

Tags: javascript

I've hooked a function to the same event of multiple controls:

```
element.onchange = SetSelected;
```

In `SetSelected` i need to know which element called me. I made the mistake of trying to do the the following:

```
element.onchange = SetSelected(element.id);
```

which of course calls the function which is not what i want.

I thought maybe the `this` keyword would provide me what i wanted but it doesn't (in the SetSelected function).

```
var element = this;
```

I'm not using jquery and prefer not to add a dependency for such a trivial task.

for those who requested it here is the complete example:

```
var imageNumber = 12;
var elementId = "cphContent_rdoSelected";

window.onload = function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= imageNumber; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId + i.toString());

        //select the first element by default
        if (i === 1) {
            SetSelected(element.id);
        }
        element.onchange = SetSelected;
    }
};

function SetSelected() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= imageNumber; i++) {
        var radioButton = this;//document.getElementById(elementId + i.toString());

        var lbl = document.getElementById("lbl" + i.toString());

        if ( id === radioButton.id) {
            if (!radioButton.hasAttribute("checked")) {
                radioButton.setAttribute("checked","");
                lbl.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        else {
            if (radioButton.hasAttribute("checked")) {
                radioButton.removeAttribute("checked");
            }
            lbl.style.display = "none";

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: *"I thought maybe the `this` keyword would provide me what i wanted but it doesn't"* It should. What is the value of `this` in your case? Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: @FelixKling Complete example added.

Comment: Looks like the `onchange` handler should work fine, but the `if (i === 1) { SetSelected(element.id); }` can't work if you want to use `this`. It should be `SetSelected.call(element);` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `this` will work if you do `element.onchange = SetSelected;`. However, your problem seems to be with

```
if (i === 1) {
    SetSelected(element.id);
}
```

That won't work because `this` won't refer to the element, it will refer to `window`. You have to set `this` explicitly, via `.call` or `.apply`:

```
if (i === 1) {
    SetSelected.call(element);
}
```

Sources to learn about `this`:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to edit my complete solution because i posted the code after i was messing with it. Does what you say still apply after my edit?

Comment: Since you have made any changes to `SetSelected(element.id);` and still use `this` inside the handler, yes.

Comment: Sorry for taking forever to mark it as the accepted answer but this definitely was the wrong answer...thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
element.onchange = function() { SetSelected(element.id); };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access which element it was from the event parameter passed into your onchange.

[Event Object](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object)

```
event.target || event.srcElement
```

That should get the element that was changed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try this...
It's a complete rewrite of what you have, though.

```
var elementId = "cphContent_rdoSelected";
var elements;

function Window_OnLoad( event ) {
    elements = document.querySelectorAll( "input[id^='" + elementId + "']" );

    elements[0].setAttribute( "checked", "" );
    document.getElementbyId( elements[0].id.replace( elementId, "lbl" ) ).style.display = "block";

    for( var i = 0, len = elements.length; len > i; ++i ) {
        elements[0].addEventListener( "change", Radio_OnChange, false );
    }
}

function Radio_OnChange( event ) {
    var element = ( event.target )? event.target: event.srcElement;
    for( var i = 0, len = elements.length; len > i; ++i ) {
        elements[i].removeAttribute( "checked" );
        document.getElementbyId( elements[i].id.replace( elementId, "lbl" ) ).style.display = "none";
    }
    element.setAttribute( "checked", "" );
    document.getElementbyId( element.id.replace( elementId, "lbl" ) ).style.display = "none";
}

window.addEventListener( "load", Window_OnLoad, false );
```